# What does the symbol $\leqq$ mean?

Tags: notation

What does the symbol $\leqq$ mean?

I am reading a paper on by Lehman on dependence, and here I find

“$\ldots$we compare the probability of any quadrant $X \leqq x$, $Y \leqq y$ under the distribution $F$ of $(X,Y)$ with the corresponding probability in the case of independence”.

Is $\leqq$ the same as $\leq$?

Comment: @January I have no idea why this question acquired downvotes. It seems perfectly clear and potentially interesting. I haven't seen the notation before myself. I have upvoted.

Comment: "Is ≦ the same as ≤?" Yes.

Comment: Thanks! Given that I have only basic mathematical education, I am always anxious that I miss some specific definition or meaning. The proofs are hard enough for me without this.

Comment: This is not a stupid question at all. Some symbols are so bizarre ! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols is a good place to visit.

Comment: Great link! How did I miss it. Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it is a symbol of less or equal "without contracting," which is the same as putting $\leq$

Answer (score 1):

it's not exactly the same by what i read on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols), there it writes

"x ≧ y means that **each component** of vector x is greater than or equal to each **corresponding** component of vector y."

so my guess is that it would not be appropriate to use regular  ≤ when talking about vectors/lists, ≤ is usually used to compare single things eg size of array but not elements of array.

you might say that if
A={1,2,6,42}
B={1,2,4,8}
A≦B

but if A={0,2,6,42}
A is NOT ≦B 
because
 A[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) is NOT ≤B[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

This is just my interpretation no one confirmed it, and there is some nonsense in wiki.

Comment: It is worth noting that the Wikipedia "list of notation" breaks things down by context. It specifically notes that *in vector analysis*, $\leqq$ and $\geqq$ can be understood elementwise.  However, just above that entry, it notes that $\leqq$ and $\geqq$ are often used as synonyms of $\le$ and $\ge$